# MS Project 2013 Does not have Sync to SharePoint Option

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I know this is short but this is the problem.  I have a user that has MS Project 2013 and his option under Save As for Sync with SharePoint is not there.  Any idea why?  I have tried looking everywhere and have not been able to find an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Found the Sync with SharePoint under File, but need more details. Trying to create a Master Schedule on SharePoint 2013 and link my MS-Project 2013 individual project schedules - am I mis-reading this answer or will this allow me to do that?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 3):

You need to sync with Microsoft Project Server. SharePoint itself does not "know" about project management.

However, you might export your project schedule to an office document and publish this document on SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

The option to sync a task list from Project 2013 to SharePoint is only available in Project Professional.  If the user has installed Project 2013 standard, the option is not there.

In Project 2013 Professional the command is File > Share, Sync with SharePoint.

To check the Project version installed, File > Account.

Answer (score -1):

MS Project 2013 Professional has the sync option.  I have Pro, but not Project Server, and it works for me.  Still working out some kinks, but it does sync.

Comment: Jane, without actually explaining where one might find the sync feature, this doesn't help us much. Do you mind expanding this out a bit more to be thorough and help folks find the option?  Thanks!